# Parse JSON string and get key value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have following JSON

```
[{ "GameID":"1109100", "StartTime": "4:00 PM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 5:30:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"101567"},{ "GameID":"1108768", "StartTime": "12:00 PM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 1:30:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"109873"},{ "GameID":"1108776", "StartTime": "12:00 PM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 1:30:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"117674"},{ "GameID":"1108742", "StartTime": "9:00 AM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 10:30:00 AM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"24621"},{ "GameID":"1108751", "StartTime": "9:00 AM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 10:30:00 AM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"24622"},{ "GameID":"1108757", "StartTime": "10:30 AM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 12:00:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"24623"},{ "GameID":"1109098", "StartTime": "2:30 PM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 4:00:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"24746"}]
```

I want to get game id, start time and end time value using TeamID. How can I do this ?

**Edit: Actual function to parse JSON from comments**

```
function doParseTime(msg){ 
    var data = $.parseJSON(msg); 
    $.each(data, function() { 
        $.each(this, function(key, val){ 
            $("#"+key).val(val); 
        }); 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Hum..Which language ?

Comment: using Javascript or Jquery

Comment: this is the function function doParseTime(msg){
var data = $.parseJSON(msg);
$.each(data, function() {


  $.each(this, function(key, val){
  $("#"+key).val(val);

  });
});

}

Comment: Please add the code to your question instead of in the comments. What is the output of your code ? What error do you have ?

Comment: Have you seen `JSON.parse`? Do you know how to access properties of objects or loop through arrays?

Comment: Look here how to parse an access JSON with jquery. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple code-snippet how to access your json-keys:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

msg = '[{ "GameID":"1109100", "StartTime": "4:00 PM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 5:30:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"101567"},{ "GameID":"1108768", "StartTime": "12:00 PM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 1:30:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"109873"},{ "GameID":"1108776", "StartTime": "12:00 PM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 1:30:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"117674"},{ "GameID":"1108742", "StartTime": "9:00 AM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 10:30:00 AM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"24621"},{ "GameID":"1108751", "StartTime": "9:00 AM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 10:30:00 AM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"24622"},{ "GameID":"1108757", "StartTime": "10:30 AM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 12:00:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"24623"},{ "GameID":"1109098", "StartTime": "2:30 PM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 4:00:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"24746"}] ';


$.each(JSON.parse(msg), function(idx, obj) {
    var gameid = obj.GameID;
    var starttime = obj.StartTime;
    var endtime = obj.EndTime;
});

});
```

Next time please read more in google about parsing and accessing json with jquery or javascript ;)

Comment: @RaviBhartiya Great. Then please mark my comment as Done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`JSON.parse()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiB0e2-gffTAhVEQo8KHXW2CZQQFgguMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON%2Fparse&usg=AFQjCNHkowMNeO8CgweprUJz3xDY9HxuPQ&sig2=oh9WWD8MBn89Pf_-OLWKSA) ,[`Array#filter`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj6zPfOgffTAhVLqo8KHQBbAxIQFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffilter&usg=AFQjCNHgB7IyOa22NG7kCsGZ1ldwMUmkiA&sig2=Fcn9R7nxzsH2WCqxPFJquw) and [`Array#map`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiQqcrmgffTAhWIPo8KHaPjAAoQFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AFQjCNG-88X_4BP621jc1yLUJwBxSXgcxg&sig2=idcftL417d6Mmb-iM0BnqQ)

```js
var data = '[{ "GameID":"1109100", "StartTime": "4:00 PM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 5:30:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"101567"},{ "GameID":"1108768", "StartTime": "12:00 PM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 1:30:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"109873"},{ "GameID":"1108776", "StartTime": "12:00 PM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 1:30:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"117674"},{ "GameID":"1108742", "StartTime": "9:00 AM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 10:30:00 AM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"24621"},{ "GameID":"1108751", "StartTime": "9:00 AM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 10:30:00 AM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"24622"},{ "GameID":"1108757", "StartTime": "10:30 AM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 12:00:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"24623"},{ "GameID":"1109098", "StartTime": "2:30 PM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 4:00:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"24746"}]';

function finding(id){
var f = JSON.parse(data).filter(a=> a.TeamID == id) //it will the matched teamId
return f.map(a=> {return  {
   GameID : a.GameID,
   StartTime: a.StartTime,
   EndTime : a.EndTime,
}}) // it add compress with three key value and iterate the all matched object's
}
console.log(finding(109873))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var yourJsonStr='[{ "GameID":"1109100", "StartTime": "4:00 PM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 5:30:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"101567"},{ "GameID":"1108768", "StartTime": "12:00 PM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 1:30:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"109873"},{ "GameID":"1108776", "StartTime": "12:00 PM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 1:30:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"117674"},{ "GameID":"1108742", "StartTime": "9:00 AM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 10:30:00 AM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"24621"},{ "GameID":"1108751", "StartTime": "9:00 AM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 10:30:00 AM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"24622"},{ "GameID":"1108757", "StartTime": "10:30 AM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 12:00:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"24623"},{ "GameID":"1109098", "StartTime": "2:30 PM", "EndTime": "1/1/1900 4:00:00 PM", "Duration": "90","TeamID":"24746"}]';

var gameInfo=eval("("+yourJsonStr+")");

$.each(gameInfo,function(i,item){
  $('#gameId').append((i + 1) + ": " + item.GameID + "<br/>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gameId"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the JSON if it's a string, then iterate over the array of objects by using 
[Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example).

From the docs:

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array
>   that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is
>   returned.

```html
   let json = JSON.parse(yourJsonString);
   let teamID= yourTeamID;
    //json is an array of javascript objects.  Iterate over them with "find";
    //This will return the first instance where the expression evaluates to true
    let foundObject = json.find(obj=>{
      return obj.TeamID=== teamID;
    });
    
    let gameID = foundObject.GameID;
    let startTime = foundObject.StartTime;
    let endTime = foundObject.EndTime;
```

Hope this helps.